# Trigger a phone call in Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8, phone-call

I need to develop an app to make a call from the Windows Phone 8 app using Visual Studio.
But I couldn't find any resources to do it.
When a button is clicked I need to call to a mobile number which is already given.
By clicking that button I must call only to that mobile number.

This is what I coded. When a given button is clicked, I this method is calling...

```
 private void HyperlinkButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();

        phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "0719957868";
        phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Gage";

        phoneCallTask.Show();
    }
```

But I get an unhandled exception.

Unhandled exception.

```
    // Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `PhoneCallTask`, you have to specify a new Capability of your app in WMAppManifest.xaml: `ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER`

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should do it:

```
PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();

phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "2065550123";
phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Gage";

phoneCallTask.Show();
```

Remember that the call is not automatically started but it prompts the user to confirm that action.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to initiate a call on windows phone

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394025(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394025%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Ok for future reference i must add this.

If you get an Unauthorized Access Exception then you need to enable `ID_CAP_PHONEDAILER` from the Capabilities section in the WMAppManifest.xml file.

See [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/unauthorized-access-exception-with-phonecalltask-in-windows-phone-8-solution)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. There comes an unhandled exception.
PhoneApp9.DLL!PhoneApp.Application_UnhandledException(object sender,c#)

Comment: @t4thilina can you specify what exception is thrown and at which line

Comment: In App.xaml.cs file at line number 100.

Comment: @t4thilina Is this code present in your app.xaml.cs?

Comment: The code that I post is presented in MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: @t4thilina what is the line 100 in App.xaml.cs looks like

Comment: @t4thilina this how the exception type looks like http://i.stack.imgur.com/vyQIZ.png . Here exception is out of memory. Can you tell me whats yours?

Comment: It is working now..... Thanx alot  for helping me...:) The problem had
with When you use PhoneCallTask, you have to specify a new Capability of your app in WMAppManifest.xaml: ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER....which was posted by lisp... Thanx again....